# JRuby Installed with rbenv does not add my gem lib directories to the load path

Tags: jruby

I installed JRuby 1.7.4 using Rbenv.  I've installed several gems using `gem install GEMNAME` from a shell where jruby-1.7.4 was set as the active ruby-- I confirmed after installation that the gems are in fact present in ~/.rbenv/versions/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems.  But, when I try to require most of my installed gems from jruby, I get an error.  Inspection shows that their lib directories are not on the `$LOAD_PATH`.  Shouldn't all the lib dirs in the gem directories I specified above automatically be there?  If not, how do I get them to show up there?

Comment: Did you ever have any luck with this issue?

Comment: @Barjavel I did, but I can't remember exactly what it was... definitely not a bug, it was something I was misunderstanding. It may have been that I was inadvertently using or misusing Bundler somehow (which configures the load path). Sorry not to be of more help!